# Spring security REST API

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-mvc, grails, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security REST Api with grails and AngularJS. And I tried the url request with postman and it is working fine. It is returning results back with used x-auth-token. But the same i tried with AngularJs but it not going further that OPTION request. 
[image: here it shows that my request is being processed up to OPTION request only.]
[image: below is the image which shows what I tried in POSTMAN. It gives the results and works fine with x-auth-token.]

[image: I have integrated spring security plugin as following. And it is working for "api/login" but further it fails.]

in 1st image here it shows that my request is being processed up to OPTION request only.
in 2nd image, shows what I tried in POSTMAN. It gives the results and works fine with x-auth-token.
in 3rd image, I have integrated spring security plugin as following. And it is working for "api/login" but further it fails.
the 4th image shows the detail response for OPTION request and then it fails to go further.
[image: 4th]

I have written grunt connect method as following

```
connect: {
options: {
port: 9000,
// Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
hostname: 'localhost',
livereload: 35729
},
proxies: [
{
context: '/crm/api',
host: 'localhost',
port: 8080
}
],
livereload: {
options: {
open: true,
base: [
'.tmp',
'<%= yeoman.app %>'
]
}
},
test: {
options: {
port: 9001,
base: [
'.tmp',
'test',
'<%= yeoman.app %>'
]
}
},
dist: {
options: {
base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
}
}
}
```

Still I have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cross-domain issue.

Your webpage is on `localhost:9000` and your backend is `localhost:8080`. These are technically 2 different domains, so you will need to either enable cross origin requests, or use a proxy to make requests forward to port `8080`.

It looks like you're using grunt, so I would suggest setting up the proxy. I use [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) to setup forwarding to my backend port:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  proxies: [
    {
      context: '/crm/api',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: hey I added proxy as you said as well as I have edited my question with the connect method I have used in grunt file. I still have the same come error. Can you please see what is actually wrong with it ?

Comment: change your ajax request url to use the same domain as your webpage, you can just use the path without domain: `/crm/api/language/index.json` and the proxy will forward it to the correct port. so when you look in the network tab it should be hitting `localhost:9000/crm/api/language/index.json`

Answer (score 2):

As explained by [agerco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22537780/1433665), the issue is cross domain issue.

For the solution, refer to this Spring Guide : [Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

As explained in above guide, you'll need to add a `Filter` bean in your application context.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:9000"); // Client URL
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Comment: Hi 
I have same problem, I setup grunt-connect-proxy in client side and i add the filter in server side. but it does not work... how can i check " Enabling Cross Origin Requests" in spring mvc project?